# Locating a trigger

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, triggers

I've created following trigger and can anybody let me know how to locate to this trigger graphically in SSMS?

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety 
ON DATABASE 
FOR DROP_TABLE
AS 
   RAISERROR ('You must disable Trigger "safety" to drop synonymsS!',10, 1)
   ROLLBACK
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SSMS,

> expand your database_name -> Expand Programmability -> Expand Database
>   trigger -> All trigger created on this database are listed here

Quoting specific part from [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx)

> Server-scoped DDL triggers appear in the SQL Server Management Studio
>   Object Explorer in the **Triggers** folder. This folder is located under
>   the **Server Objects** folder. Database-scoped DDL triggers appear in the
>   **Database Triggers** folder. This folder is located under the
>   **Programmability** folder of the corresponding database.